# Insert JSON file into MongoDB - JSON has metadata and another list with the actual data

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoimport

I used `mongoimport -d test -c BB --file=bb.json`

also I tried `mongoimport -d test -c BB --jsonArray --file=bb.json`

they only insert it as one record instead of multiple records ( 2900 approx )

I know that in MongoDB the data should be in key:value pair and this data is in list for but with metadata as well. Can I import data in this form itself without converting it into key : value pairs ?

Thanks
Here is the Data or info from input file bb.json which I am trying to import

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Start of DATA File
{ "data": [
        [
            "1",
            "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
            "NA",
            "Port Blair",
            "G.B Pant Hospital",
            "Atlanta Point",
            "744104",
            "03192 230628",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "[=12]12",
            "[=93]93"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
            "NA",
            "Port Blair",
            "I.N.H.S. Dhanvantri",
            "Minni Bay",
            "744103",
            "03192 248759",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA"
        ],
.....  # RECORDS 
        [
            "2946",
            "West Bengal",
            "NA",
            "Murshidabad",
            "Lalbagh S.D. Hospital Blood Bank",
            "P.O. Lalbagh",
            "742149",
            "03482 270247",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "NA",
            "[=24]24",
            "[=88]88"
        ]
    ],
    "fields": [
        { "id": "a", "label": "id", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "b", "label": "state", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "c", "label": "city", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "d", "label": "district", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "e", "label": "h_name", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "f", "label": "address", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "g", "label": "pincode", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "h", "label": "contact", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "i", "label": "helpline", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "j", "label": "fax", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "k", "label": "category", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "l", "label": "website", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "m", "label": "email", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "n", "label": "blood_component", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "o", "label": "blood_group", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "p", "label": "service_time", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "q", "label": "latitude", "type": "string" },
        { "id": "r", "label": "longitude", "type": "string" }
    ]
}

END of DATA File -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a little Python Program to convert it to suitable JSON format which MongoDB was able to use to import to MongoDB.

Here it is :

```
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html
# On Command Line use "cat some.json | python -m json.tool"

import pprint
import json


fh = open ( 'Blood_bank_updated-sep_2015.json', 'r' )

# json_bb1 = json.dumps(json_bb, indent = 4, sort_keys = False/True)

#  To parse a STRING use "json.loads"
#  To parse a FILE   use "json.load"
#     Please note the difference is load[s] - s for string

json_bb = json.load( fh )

print 'json_bb :', type(json_bb)


var_i = 0
for key in json_bb.keys():
  var_i = var_i + 1
  print var_i, key

fields = range ( len( json_bb['fields'] ) )

var_i = 0
for label in json_bb['fields']:
  fields[var_i] = label['label']
  var_i = var_i + 1
  # print var_i, label
  # print label['label']

# Change "id" to "_id" for MongoDB "_id"
if fields[0] == "id":
  fields[0] = "_id"

print "fields :", fields

fhand = open("BB_MongoDB.json", 'w')

var_i = 0
for values in json_bb['data']:
  rec = list()
  for index in range( len( fields ) ):

    rec.append( ( fields[index], values[index] ) )

  temp_data = dict( rec )

  temp_data2 = json.dumps( temp_data, sort_keys = True )

  fhand.write( temp_data2 + u"\n" )

  if var_i < 22:
      print var_i, "Values :", values, "\n\n"
      print "Index :", index, "Record :" , rec
      print "\n\n\nIndex :", var_i, "Mongo_BB :" , bb_mongo
  var_i += 1


quit()
```